# Understanding the use of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, double-pointer

Hi I' have come across to a code that I have hard time to understand why it is working and I would appreciate if someone could explain me
Here is the code This is actually a very simplified version of the real code which can be found here http://acts.nersc.gov/hypre/example10/ex10.cxx.html

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
double ***elemStiff = new double**[10];
int i, k;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    elemStiff[i] = new double*[4];
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        elemStiff[i][k] = new double[4];
    }

    double **A = elemStiff[i];
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        A[k][k] = 2/3.;

    A[0][1] = A[1][0] = -1/6.;
    A[0][2] = A[2][0] = -1/3.;
    A[0][3] = A[3][0] = -1/6.;
    A[1][2] = A[2][1] = -1/6.;
    A[1][3] = A[3][1] = -1/3.;
        A[2][3] = A[3][2] = -1/6.;
    }
    std::cout << elemStiff[1][0][0] << std::endl;
}
```

In short, here we initialize and fill the values of the elemStiff array which has 10 rows and each row is a 4x4 matrix.

What is very weird to me is that the code fills in the entries of elemStiff array with the help of the double **A = elemStiff[i];

When I first saw I though it would give an error but it works!. The values passed on A, they are passed at the same time on elemStiff array, but I dont understand why it works

Thank you

Comment: Because they point to the same thing in memory, the same values are updated for both arrays.

Comment: I made a rule for myself to never have `***` in my code. It gives me a headache. And here it's just masking a 10x4x4 array, which can be created directly. Unless, of course, this is a simplification for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thank you, and I guess that if I delete the elemStiff its enough I dont need to delete the A array also

Comment: You're a [ThreeStarProgrammer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with simpler version:

```
int* array = new int[10];
int* ptr = array;            // equivalent to ptr = &array[0]

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ptr[i] = i;              // writing into the memory that ptr points to

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout << array[i];   // outputs: 0123456789
```

In this example we create a pointer `ptr` that points to the first element of `array`. Then when we are writing into the memory that `ptr` points to, we are actually writing into that `array`. So then when we check values of `array` elements, we can see they were properly initialized.

Your code is pretty much the same, there's just an array of 10 two-dimensional arrays:

```
double ***elemStiff = new double**[10];
```

And then just like we used `ptr` in my simple example, you use a temporary pointer `A` to make it point to each of those 10 two-dimensional arrays:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    double **A = elemStiff[i];
```